# Subview with a different controller than its parent?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to create a subview with a different controller than its parent?

Specifically, my app has `groups` and `users`. Viewing an individual group is handled by `App.GroupView`, which is connected to `App.GroupController`, which is a subclass of `Ember.ObjectController` (since a group is an object).

Within the group view, I want to have another view that shows a list of the users within the group. So my `group.handlebars` template looks something like this:

```
<header>
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <p>{{description}}</p>
</header>
{{view App.GroupUsersView}}
```

What I'd like to do is to connect `App.GroupUsersView` to its own controller, which would be a subclass of `App.ArrayController`, since it represents a list of users. And its content would be set to the `users` attribute of the group.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{{render}}` helper for that like this:

```
{{render 'group/users' users}}
```

Reference: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/30/ember-1-0-rc2.html

Comment: Awesome, totally forgot about the render helper / didn't really understand how it works.